# Device's mdm communication log

Tags: ios, mdm

I need to check how device is communicating via mdm protocol. 
Especially I have to check why device rejects installation of Managed domains profile (iOS 8 specific)

Before iOS 8 I used to do it using iPhone configuration utility (ICU), but now ICU doesn't support iOS 8 and it looks like won't support anymore. Apple suggests to use apple configurator.

I've looked through the all topics here, but haven't seen anything relevant to my question.

So, in general is it possible to check mdm communication logs?

Thanks!

P.S.
I am not an iOS developer, so I am not familiar with the development tools, 
but as prerequisites I have macbook with installed xcode. 
Btw, checked device's log via xcode, but didn't found any relevant information.

Comment: It seems I found console in the xcode. You have to open Window\Devices then select your device and you have to find "triangle" button at the bottom of the window. At least it shows some mdm communication.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've discovered the issue in your profile or MDM delivery, but I will point out that Managed Domains payloads require that the device is supervised and so confirm the device is supervised before trying to install the profile with said payload.  If it is not, remove the profile, erase the device & supervise it, and then install the profile.